# startActivity method is not working in my listview onitemclicklistener

Tags: android

I checked all the previous questions regarding this issue, but none of them are helpful to me.

I am trying to open new activity in my listview `onItemClickListener` but it is not opening the new activity. In the android monitor, it shows

> "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN".

The `onItemClickListener` is not responding when I click that item of my listview... Is it possible to open?

The activity is successfully running, but I am unable to listen for list click events.

How to correct this?

Here is my class :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.R;
import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.activity.Activity_Add_Enquiry;
import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.activity.Activity_Enquiry_Description;
import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.adapter.Adapter_Enquiry_List;
import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.global.App_Config;
import com.example.banyan.simtaa_erp.global.Session_Manager;
import com.sdsmdg.tastytoast.TastyToast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;

import static com.willy.ratingbar.BaseRatingBar.TAG;


    public class Fragment_Enquiry_List extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

        public Fragment_Enquiry_List() {

        }

        private FloatingActionButton fab_enquiry;

        String str_user_name, str_user_id,str_select_task_id;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        private SpotsDialog dialog_load_more;

        public static RequestQueue queue;

        Session_Manager session;

        private SwipeRefreshLayout enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout;
        private ListView enquiry_listView;

        public static final String TAG_ID= "id";
        public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_ID = "cus_id";
        public static final String TAG_IMAGE_ENQUIRY = "image";
        public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
        public static final String TAG_DATE_ENQUIRY = "date";
        public static final String TAG_PROJECT_STATUS = "project_status";
        public static final String TAG_CREATED_USERID = "created_userid";
        public static final String TAG_CREATED_USERROLE = "created_userrole";
        public static final String TAG_CREATED_DATETIME = "created_datetime";
        public static final String TAG_CUSTOMER_DETAILS = "customer_details";

        int int_starting_item_no = 0, int_last_item_no = 0, int_load_more_count = 100;

        public Adapter_Enquiry_List Adapter;

        static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> enquiry_list;

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enquiry_list, container, false);

            session = new Session_Manager(getActivity());
            session.checkLogin();

            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

            str_user_id = user.get(Session_Manager.KEY_USER_ID);
            str_user_name = user.get(Session_Manager.KEY_USER_NAME);

            System.out.println("USER ID from Session ::::" + str_user_id);
            System.out.println("USER NAME from Session ::::" + str_user_name);

            enquiry_listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_enquiry_list);
            fab_enquiry = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_enquiry);

            enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout);
            enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

            enquiry_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()

            enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(true);
                        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        Activity_Get_Enquiry_List(int_starting_item_no, int_load_more_count);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });

            enquiry_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    System.out.println("Event Trigered by Item" );

                    String str_enquiry_id = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_ID);
                    String str_customer_id = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                    String str_image_enquiry = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE_ENQUIRY);
                    String str_description_enquiry = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String str_date_enquiry = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_DATE_ENQUIRY);
                    String str_project_status = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS);
                    String str_created_userid = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_CREATED_USERID);
                    String str_created_userrole = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_CREATED_USERROLE);
                    String str_created_datetime = enquiry_list.get(position).get(TAG_CREATED_DATETIME);

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("enquiry_id", str_enquiry_id);
                    editor.putString("customer_id", str_customer_id);
                    editor.putString("image_enquiry", str_image_enquiry);
                    editor.putString("description_enquiry", str_description_enquiry);
                    editor.putString("date_enquiry", str_date_enquiry);
                    editor.putString("project_status", str_project_status);
                    editor.putString("created_userid", str_created_userid);
                    editor.putString("created_role", str_created_userrole);
                    editor.putString("created_datetime", str_created_datetime);

                    editor.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),Activity_Enquiry_Description.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


            enquiry_listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    str_select_task_id = enquiry_list.get(pos).get(TAG_ID);

                    Delete_Task_alert();

                    return true;

                }
            });



            return rootView;

        }

        private void Activity_Get_Enquiry_List(final int int_starting_item_no, final int int_load_more_count) {

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, App_Config.url_list_enquiry, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(TAG_CUSTOMER_DETAILS, response.toString());
                    Log.d("TAG_ENQUIRY_LIST", response.toString());

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        System.out.println("REG 00" + obj);

                        int success = obj.getInt("success");

                        System.out.println("REG" + success);

                        if (success == 1) {

                            JSONArray enquiry = obj.getJSONArray("Enquiry");

                            for (int i = 0; enquiry.length() > i; i++) {

                                JSONObject obj_one = enquiry.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str_enquiry_id = obj_one.getString(TAG_ID);
                                String str_customer_id = obj_one.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                                String str_image_enquiry = obj_one.getString(TAG_IMAGE_ENQUIRY);
                                String str_description_enquiry = obj_one.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                                String str_date_enquiry = obj_one.getString(TAG_DATE_ENQUIRY);
                                String str_project_status = obj_one.getString(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS);
                                String str_created_userid = obj_one.getString(TAG_CREATED_USERID);
                                String str_created_userrole = obj_one.getString(TAG_CREATED_USERROLE);
                                String str_created_datetime = obj_one.getString(TAG_CREATED_DATETIME);

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put(TAG_ID, str_enquiry_id);
                                map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_ID, str_customer_id);
                                map.put(TAG_IMAGE_ENQUIRY, str_image_enquiry);
                                map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, str_description_enquiry);
                                map.put(TAG_DATE_ENQUIRY, str_date_enquiry);
                                map.put(TAG_PROJECT_STATUS, str_project_status);
                                map.put(TAG_CREATED_USERID, str_created_userid);
                                map.put(TAG_CREATED_USERROLE, str_created_userrole);
                                map.put(TAG_CREATED_DATETIME, str_created_datetime);

                                enquiry_list.add(map);

                                System.out.println("HASHMAP ARRAY" + enquiry_list);


                            }

                            Adapter = new Adapter_Enquiry_List(getActivity(), enquiry_list);
                            enquiry_listView.setAdapter(Adapter);
                            enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(false);


                        } else {

                            TastyToast.makeText(getContext(), "OOPS FAILED TO LOAD", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.WARNING);

                        }

                        LoadMoreButtonVisible();
                        enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(false);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    enquiry_list_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(false);

                }

            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("user_id", str_user_id);
                    params.put("start",""+ int_starting_item_no);
                    params.put("limit",""+ int_load_more_count);

                    System.out.println("user_id " + str_user_id);
                    System.out.println("start " + int_starting_item_no);
                    System.out.println("limit " + int_load_more_count);

                    return params;

                }

            };


            queue.add(request);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are clickable UI elements like Button, Imagebutton are present in child view of list/Recyclerview, they can take control of click events. So, Recyclerview would not get chance to click event.

Please set  `android:focusable="false"` for all child clickable view. Then your itemclick will work.

You can also use following property in parent view that prevent child view getting focus.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Samir Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

You implement wrong method of list item click listener, just replace this

```
 enquiry_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}
}
```

To:

```
enquiry_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}}
```

Comment: When I add (new OnItemClickListener) its asking import class. when I try to use (alt+enter) then I entered, it shows (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() In that import class.